# Examples of Business Cards?

Tags: print-design

I'm looking for some inspiration flip through. What are some places that you visit for business card examples or galleries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For inspiration you should see less and think more, because there is nothing stronger than your own ideas. That said, a few places to research this:

1. [Card Design Inspiration](http://logodesignerblog.com/creative-business-cards-design-inspiration/)
2. [Business Card Design](http://dzineblog.com/2011/02/53-best-business-card-design-inspiration.html)
3. [Most Beautiful and Creative cards](http://naldzgraphics.net/inspirations/60-most-beautiful-and-creative-business-cards-design/)
4. [Business card Inspiration](http://ohsobeautifulpaper.com/2011/04/business-card-inspiration-2/)
5. [Top 8 Sites For Business Card Inspiration](http://inspirationfeed.com/2010/04/top-8-websites-for-business-card-inspiration/)

Answer (score 3):

I looked at hundreds, maybe even thousands before I made my business cards.  Unfortunately, I only bookmarked a few.

Outside of some examples, I can only offer a few bits of advice:

- Avoid contemplating the silly or ultra-fancy ones that would cost $1 a card, such as the metal ones, the peanut ones, etc.  Unless you plan on making several hundred thousand a year, you'd be wasting money, or if there is no chance that you'll get them, you're just wasting your time if you go to sites that focus on business cards like those.
- Follow the recommendations made in this question: [Making a business card. Any advice?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/830/making-a-business-card-any-advice)
- Use 300 DPI and use a 1/8" bleed on all edges of the card, so your design's resolution should be 3.75x2.25.

**My Examples**

1. [Example 1](http://www.dzinepress.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/881.jpg)
2. [Example 2](http://www.graphicdesignblog.org/images/business-card-designs/business-card-design-21.gif)
3. [25 Examples](http://www.bestbusinesscard.net/25-best-business-cards-for-february-2010)
4. [Coffee-Themed Examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=business%20card%20coffee&tbm=isch&biw=1680&bih=865)
5. [18 Examples](http://freelanceswitch.com/general/18-smokin-hot-business-card-designs/)

Here's my business card, just to show you for some inspiration:

[image: Front Side]
 [image: Back Side]

Comment: back end is good

Comment: What's too big?  They're normal 3.5x2 business cards... lol!

Answer (score 0):

You can always try for google not sure if what you looking.

[Can look some creative business card](http://www.google.pt/search?um=1&hl=pt-PT&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3apt-PT%3aofficial&biw=1263&bih=591&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=creative%20business%20card&aq=f&aqi=g-L10&aql=&oq=)

Comment: Perry beat you to this. :)